# Flat nested dict, where new key will be tuple of all nested keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict like this:

```
previous_dict = {
    'dict_1': 'dict_1',
    'dict_2': {
        'dict_2_1': 'dict_2_1',
        'dict_2_2': 'dict_2_2'
    },
    'dict_3': 3,
    'dict_4': None,
    'dict_5': dict()
}
```

I have wrote a function to flat the dict with all keys as tuple which outputs as:

```
previously_expected_dict = {}
for key, value in previous_dict.items():
    if type(value) == dict:
        for k, v in value.items():
            previously_expected_dict[(key, k)] = v
    else:
        previously_expected_dict[(key,)] = value
```

**output:**

```
print(previously_expected_dict)
{
    ('dict_1',): 'dict_1',
    ('dict_2', 'dict_2_1'): 'dict_2_1',
    ('dict_2', 'dict_2_2'): 'dict_2_2',
    ('dict_3',): 3,
    ('dict_4',): None
}
```

> `dict_5` is discarded as it does not have any value

---

Now the requirement has changed and The dict could have any number of nesting

```
new_dict = {
    'dict_1': {
        'dict_1_1': {
            'dict_1_1_1': 'dict_1_1_1',
            'dict_1_1_2': 'dict_1_1_2'
        }
    },
    'dict_2': {
        'dict_2_1': 'dict_2_1',
        'dict_2_2': 'dict_2_2'
    },
    'dict_3': 'dict_3',
    'dict_4': dict()
}
```

Code I have tried so far

```
def make_flat(my_dict):
    nd = dict()
    keys = []

    def loop_me(value):
        nonlocal keys
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            for k, v in value.items():
                keys.append(k)
                loop_me(v)
        else:
            nd[tuple(keys)] = value
            keys.pop(-1)

    loop_me(my_dict)
    return nd


print(make_flat(new_dict))
```

But I received extra keys in tuple

```
{
    ('dict_1', 'dict_1_1', 'dict_1_1_1'): 'dict_1_1_1',  # Perfect
    ('dict_1', 'dict_1_1', 'dict_1_1_2'): 'dict_1_1_2',  # Perfect
    ('dict_1', 'dict_1_1', 'dict_2', 'dict_2_1'): 'dict_2_1',  # Error, Expected is: ('dict_2', 'dict_2_1')
    ('dict_1', 'dict_1_1', 'dict_2', 'dict_2_2'): 'dict_2_2',  # Error, Expected is: ('dict_2', 'dict_2_2')
    ('dict_1', 'dict_1_1', 'dict_2', 'dict_3'): 'dict_3'  # Error, Expected is: ('dict_3',)
}
```

**Final Expected Output:**

```
output = {
    ('dict_1', 'dict_1_1', 'dict_1_1_1'): 'dict_1_1_1',
    ('dict_1', 'dict_1_1', 'dict_1_1_2'): 'dict_1_1_2',
    ('dict_2', 'dict_2_1'): 'dict_2_1',
    ('dict_2', 'dict_2_2'): 'dict_2_2',
    ('dict_3',): 'dict_3'
}
```

I tried writing with the for loop and recursive function, Failed.

Comment: Why use a stack when you could have used recursion?

Comment: @DroidX86, I am sorry, i did not understand what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
def flatten(d, c = []):
  for a, b in d.items():
    if not isinstance(b, dict):
       yield (tuple(c+[a]), b)
    else:
       yield from flatten(b, c+[a])

print(dict(flatten(previous_dict)))
```

Output:

```
{('dict_1',): 'dict_1', ('dict_2', 'dict_2_1'): 'dict_2_1', ('dict_2', 'dict_2_2'): 'dict_2_2', ('dict_3',): 3, ('dict_4',): None}
```

With `new_dict`:

```
{('dict_1', 'dict_1_1', 'dict_1_1_1'): 'dict_1_1_1', ('dict_1', 'dict_1_1', 'dict_1_1_2'): 'dict_1_1_2', ('dict_2', 'dict_2_1'): 'dict_2_1', ('dict_2', 'dict_2_2'): 'dict_2_2', ('dict_3',): 'dict_3'}
```

Comment: Perfect, How cleanly you have done! Perfect, Thanks!

Comment: Note that using a mutable object such as `[]` as a default parameter makes the function misbehave on the second call.

Comment: @blhsing That would only be the case only if a `c.append` call was used.

Comment: @Ajax1234 True. I would personally make it a tuple instead just to be clear that it isn't meant to be altered though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function that iterates through the dict items and prepends the keys to the tuples of sub-keys returned by the recursive calls:

```
def flatten(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for s, i in flatten(v):
                yield (k, *s), i
        else:
            yield (k,), v
```

so that `dict(flatten(new_dict))` returns:

```
{('dict_1', 'dict_1_1', 'dict_1_1_1'): 'dict_1_1_1', ('dict_1', 'dict_1_1', 'dict_1_1_2'): 'dict_1_1_2', ('dict_2', 'dict_2_1'): 'dict_2_1', ('dict_2', 'dict_2_2'): 'dict_2_2', ('dict_3',): 'dict_3'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used `deep` variable to determine & correct keys and `make_flat` functions returns your desired output, However, @Ajax1234 done it more clearly.

```
def make_flat(dict_):
    new_dict = dict()
    keys = []

    def loop_recursively(value, deep=0):
        nonlocal keys
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            deep += 1
            for k, v in value.items():
                keys.append(k)
                loop_recursively(v, deep)
            else:
                deep -= 1
        else:
            keys = keys[-deep:]
            new_dict[tuple(keys)] = value
            keys.pop(-1)

    loop_recursively(dict_)
    return new_dict
```

Comment: It works, Thanks for your effort, however i will go with @Ajax1234 than my approach.